# how to validate email pattern using azure policy?

Tags: azure-policy

Could you please provide me the azure policy code for validating  email pattern?.

Please find examples in the below:

```
kiran@ch.gmail.com
naresh@jk.gmail.com
*@*.gmail.com
```

Comment: It is almost impossible to validate email addresses.

see : 
https://medium.com/hackernoon/the-100-correct-way-to-validate-email-addresses-7c4818f24643

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score -1):

That is not support with Policy today. Policy is not aware of users so can't validate emails.